# What does train and test PPL mean?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, terminology

I'm reading a machine learning paper, and in it, there is train and test **NLL** and **PPL**.

I know that NLL stands for "negative log-likelihood". But I don't know about PPL. What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PPL stands for [perplexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity). This quantity is directly computable from the negative log-likelihood (and the number of samples), so it's odd that the authors would report both. A given sub-discipline tends to prefer one or the other.